# how to update the values of the edited row using knockout datatables extension?

Tags: knockout.js

Im loading more than a 1000 rows in a datatables using the knockout extension.im mapping these items into an observable array using map.fromjs and it realy slows down the initial loading of the page.

to avoid this slow initial load up I tried to set the observable array to be filled with just plain json objects meaning the 1000+ objects contained in the array are not observable.

but since the objects are not observable then when editions were done on the plain objects the changes weren't being seen in the datatables grid because there is no binding. is there a way to get the ui to change to accommodate the new values of the plain edited json object?

I even tried removing the edited object from the observable array and reading it with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You should setup every editable property of every item as observable. For example:

```
self.items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(
    datasource,
    function(row){
        return {
            id: row.id,
            title: ko.observable(row.title)
        };
    }
));
```

*Don't care about thousands of objects; this amount is not so big.*

Take a look how it works with 2,500 objs: http://jsfiddle.net/HfzvG/

Comment: do you know of an alternative faster way to map.fromjs, this slows down the initial load up of the page, thats why I wanted to use plain js objects instead of observables.

Answer (score 0):

2500 objecs isn't a lot... imo... however, I had project that was trying to do this with 90,000 + rows and it actually killed chrome... The solution was serverside paging... I created knockout bound paging that would request a small amount of rows per page. These parameters were handled in my stored procedure. You could also handle the paging parameters in your server side language as well. This required more trips to the server, but the trade off was well worth it..

some SQL code here...

```
declare @rowCount int = 25;

Select MainSearchWithRowNumbers.*       
FROM
(SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER () As RowNumber
    ,Count(*) OVER () as TotalRows
    ,CEILING(CAST(Count(*) OVER () as FLOAT) / CAST(@rowCount as FLOAT)) AS TotalPages
    ,*
FROM
    (
     SELECT 
        -- ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CarcassRemovalId) AS AbsRowNumber
        Count(*) OVER () AS AbsTotalRows
        ,CEILING(CAST(Count(*) OVER () AS FLOAT) / CAST(@rowCount AS FLOAT)) AS AbsTotalPages
        ,*
     FROM YOURTABLE) 
    ) as MainSearch
) as MainSearchWithRowNumbers
WHERE
    (@page is null)
     or (
                (RowNumber <= @page * @rowCount)
            and (RowNumber > (@page - 1) * @rowCount)
    )
```